# SSIS Derived column transformation no Inputs

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, bids

I dont know if this is possible. In SSIS Derived column transformation, can you run the package without any inputs?

For example, you have a data flow task and within that you just have your Derived column transformation act as your source. The reason being, you can access the system variables in this way without writing a script for it. Below is the screenshot that I am trying to achieve. The package does not fail, but I cant see anything on the data viewer (it doesnt even get executed). Any help is appreciated. Than[image]ks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't make sense. Even if it was possible, the "derived column" transformation applies to every row on your source; so in your case, you wouldn't have any rows with your new column, so you wouldn't be able to use it anyway.

Comment: Thats strange. I thought that you could create new columns on the fly without depending on the input. If you access the system variables in this transformation, you could still create new columns based on these variables. Thats what I was trying to do. But doesnt look like thats possible.

Comment: @RajivVarma - If you want to use the system variables, you can. But it doesn't make sense to do it on your dataflow. You can go to the control flow and use the variables that you like on the "execute sql task" container

Comment: I'm trying to do this too for the following scenario:
1) In Control Flow, Execute SQL Task to get a Result Set...2) Feed Result Set as Collection to a ForEach container, set each column by index as a new user scoped Variable...3) Inside ForEach container, I have a Data Flow task, which I want to execute for each row...4) Inside Data Flow, I want to start with a Derived Column task that essentially recreates the current row of data from the ForEach container for use in the Data Flow. Is this possible? As OP mentioned, I get no errors, but there are 0 rows being processed in the Data Flow